# Invalid Parameter #3: "(x86)\Syslog\logs"

Tags: batch-file

Hello seeing if someone could help with this batch file. Not really a program but deemed with the task of moving files from ProgramFiles(x86) to a network drive.
After creating the script and running I get: 
"Invalid Parameter #3: "(x86)\Syslog\logs"
from the script below.

```
@echo off 
title move files
echo Move from C to E
robocopy C:\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs C:\Users\admin.gnorthern\Desktop\Newfolder" /move /COPY:U /MAXAGE:30
pause
```

I got this one from another post but with out results.
I have also tried the below int the script with similar results

```
robocopy C:\"PROGRA~2\%\Syslogd\Logs
```

Comment: Why do you put the quotation marks in such weird positions? try to put *each path argument* within quotes...

Comment: Like so: robocopy C:\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs" "C:\Users\admin.gnorthern\Desktop\Newfolder" /move /COPY:U /MAXAGE:30.

Comment: Like so:                                                                                           robocopy C:\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs" "C:\Users\admin.gnorthern\Desktop\Newfolder" /move /COPY:U /MAXAGE:30.            I get Invalid Parameter#3  "x86)%\Syslogd\Logs C:\Users\admin.gnorthern\Desktop\Newfolder"

Comment: No, you are excluding `C:\` from the source, but it should be included within the `""` also...

Answer (score 0):

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%` already contains drive specification:

```
==> echo %ProgramFiles(x86)%
C:\Program Files (x86)

==>
```

Your `C:\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs"` would result to invalid path

```
C:\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Syslogd\Logs"
```

Hence, omit leading `C:\` as follows:

```
robocopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs" "C:\Users\admin.gnorthern\Desktop\Newfolder" /move /COPY:U /MAXAGE:30
```

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, that got the script going, but would you know why no files are moving over? Do you know if I need to specify the file type?

Comment: Sorry @gnorth02. This exceeds original topic; please ask another question.  However, `robocopy` uses pretty verbose output; read and analyze it before asking. Or maybe you need to have the command prompt to be run as administrator. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I end up using the script below on the server and it works great.                                                                                   @echo off 
robocopy "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs" "E:\Test" /move /minage:30
pause

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for all the replies: The below worked for me.

@echo off robocopy 
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Syslogd\Logs" "E:\Test" /move /minage:30
pause